# How do I get the dot product but without the summation

Tags: python, numpy

consider array's `a` and `b`

```
a = np.array([
        [-1, 1, 5],
        [-2, 3, 0]
    ])
b = np.array([
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 2, 3],
    ])
```

Looking at

```
d = a.T.dot(b)
d

array([[-1, -5, -6],
       [ 1,  7,  9],
       [ 5,  5,  0]])
```

`d[0, 0]` is `-1`.  and is the sum of `a[:, 0] * b[:, 0]`.  I'd like a 2x2 array of vectors where the `[0, 0]` position would be `a[:, 0] * b[:, 0]`.

with the above `a` and `b`, I'd expect

```
d = np.array([[a[:, i] * b[:, j] for j in range(a.shape[1])] for i in range(b.shape[1])])

d

array([[[-1,  0],
        [-1, -4],
        [ 0, -6]],

       [[ 1,  0],
        [ 1,  6],
        [ 0,  9]],

       [[ 5,  0],
        [ 5,  0],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

The sum of `d` along `axis==2` should be the dot product `a.T.dot(b)`

```
d.sum(2)

array([[-1, -5, -6],
       [ 1,  7,  9],
       [ 5,  5,  0]])
```

#### Question

What is the most efficient way of getting `d`?

Comment: what is wrong with `a.T.dot(b)`?

Comment: @karakfa I don't wan't the sums.  I want the vectors prior to the summation.  I want `d`.

Comment: A more readable and slightly more efficient version would be `np.array([[i*j for j in b.T]  for i in a.T])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
In [219]: a
Out[219]: 
array([[-1,  1,  5],
       [-2,  3,  0]])

In [220]: b
Out[220]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 3]])

In [221]: a.T[:,None,:] * b.T[None,:,:]
Out[221]: 
array([[[-1,  0],
        [-1, -4],
        [ 0, -6]],

       [[ 1,  0],
        [ 1,  6],
        [ 0,  9]],

       [[ 5,  0],
        [ 5,  0],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

Or...

```
In [231]: (a[:,None,:] * b[:,:,None]).T
Out[231]: 
array([[[-1,  0],
        [-1, -4],
        [ 0, -6]],

       [[ 1,  0],
        [ 1,  6],
        [ 0,  9]],

       [[ 5,  0],
        [ 5,  0],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

Comment: Could this be generalized for other shapes?

Comment: @ayhan It is basically broadcasting, so it is already quite general.  If you have something specific in mind, you should probably make it an actual SO question.

Comment: OK I somehow thought the shape of the arrays (12x7  instead of 4x3 for example) would require different new axes but they are both 2D I guess that's what is important here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Most efficient one would be with `broadcasting` as shown in [`@Warren Weckesser's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38981589/3293881) as we are basically dealing with element-wise multiplication without any `sum-reduction`.

An alternative one with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) would be like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->jki',a,b)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is quicker.  If I confirm it, this will be my answer.

Comment: @piRSquared Well I did time it at my end on a larger dataset and was a bit slower than broadcasting, which makes sense to me as `einsum` isn't meant just for broadcasting, it's meant for reduction purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
for r in a.T:
    print(np.multiply(r,b.T))

[[-1  0]
 [-1 -4]
 [ 0 -6]]
[[1 0]
 [1 6]
 [0 9]]
[[5 0]
 [5 0]
 [0 0]]
```